Nondimensionalizing and normalizing a partial differential equation
I am trying to understand how to normalize the partial differential equation below. I know how to make it dimensionless but I do not fully understand how to normalize it. I know you're supposed to use the right characteristic scales in order to normalize it and I feel that I am but not sure how to deal with the masses. Here
S is surface density which is equal to m/pi*r^2, $m$ is 1 solar mass which is approximately 2e33 g, M = 10^8 solar masses and G is the universal gravitational constant which in cgs equals 6.673e-8 cm^3/gs^-2
$\large \frac{\partial S}{\partial t} = 1000 \frac{m}{M^{3/2}} \sqrt{G}r^{3/2}S\frac{\partial S}{\partial r}$
I begin by defining the dimensionless variables:
$\large S^* = \frac{S}{S_c}, \quad t^* =\frac{t}{t_c},\quad r^* = \frac{r}{r_c}$
The characteristic scales I choose are as follows:
$\large S_c = \frac{m}{r_0^2}, \quad t_c = \frac{r_0^{3/2}}{1000\sqrt{GM}}, \quad r_c=r_0$
Solving for the dimensional parameters in terms of the dimensionless ones and substituting them in I get after some algebra the following:
$\large \frac{\partial \tilde{S}}{\partial \tilde{t}} =  \frac{m^2}{M^2} \left(\tilde{r}^{3/2} \tilde{S} \frac{\partial \tilde{S}}{\partial \tilde{r}}\right)$
I feel I did the nondimensionalization correct however it can't be fully correct because the m^2/M^2 gives me 10^-16 which throws off the scaling completely. I was trying to see how I could handle this by possibly defining a characteristic mass but I am not sure how to deal with the two masses. I would really appreciate any help with this.
